# Permission Denial: start Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app, I have to use Intent.setClassName or setComponent to start an activity in another package. There is no problem when I use Intent.setClass like 
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), org.iustb.knowledebase.animation.transparent.MainTransparentActivity.class);
The suggestions to solve this problem on the web is that adding  or android:exported="true" to the target activity in the AndroidManifest, but it doesn't work.
Is there anybody can help me?
 i wrote the below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(cursor.getString(pIndex), cursor.getString(cIndex));
startActivity(intent);
```

manifest file settings of the target activity:

```
<activity android:name="org.iustb.knowledebase.animation.transparent.MainTransparentActivity"
                android:exported="true"></activity>
```

Comment: Could you post the output from `LogCat`, this will help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure the values that the `cursor` returns the are correct ones?

The first parameter of the `setClassName()` should be the **application package** name, not the package where the Activity beings started is.

Assume the application package is: `com.testandroid`, but you want to start the other activity from the `com.testandroid.other` package, then your code should look like this:

```
intent.setClassName("com.testandroid", "com.testandroid.other.OtherActivity");
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a conflict between `package=com.example.myApplication` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the `<manifest>` tag and `applicationId` in the `build.gradle:app` module under the  `defaultConfig` tag. hope it would help.